# Where is this statement "Destiny determines the consequences...." found?

Tags: karma, identification-request, vidura, destiny

Does anyone know the source for the following quote?

> Destiny determines the consequences of our actions but not the actions themselves.

I heard that this is told by Vidura to Dhritarastra. This [article](http://iskconbangalore.co.in/is-destiny-in-your-hand/) also claims the same.

Comment: This is most probably a misquote. Exact statement is not found but related is found. If you add some reference where you heard, it would help us finding sooner.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma may be, can you share related one atleast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a popular conversation between Vidura and Dhritarashtra. It is called Vidura Neeti or Vidura Geeta which extends for nine chapters i.e., chapter 33 to 41 of the *Udyoga Parva* of the Mahabharata.

The exact quote is not present in the Vidura Neeti but a verse which implies the same i.e., destiny is stronger than one's actions or will is present. This is not said by Vidura. It is Dhritarashtra who said that.

From [Section 40](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05040.htm) of Udyoga Parva (Translated by Kisari Mohan Ganguli)

> Although, however, I incline in my mind towards the Pandavas even as thou teachest me to do, yet as soon as I come in contact with Duryodhana it turneth off in a different way. **No creature is able to avert fate. Indeed, Destiny, I think, is certain to take its course; individual exertion is futile**.

He says that as a response to Vidura's discourse to declare Yudhistira as the king and treat Pandavas equal with his own sons.